# UML Diagrams for a non-database Projects

Tags: c#, sorting, uml, project, class-diagram

I am doing a project on Sorting Algorithm Visualizer in Dot Net. As the very step in all projects is UML diagrams. My project is simple as user will only select number of Arrays to generate in a panel and sorting Algorithm to sort it *if if goes smoothly I will add sorting speed option*.

**There is No Database in my project.**

I have Created Sequence and Activity diagram, but now finds difficulty to create these diagrams:
Class diagram
Components diagram
Deployment diagram
Collaboration diagram
State Diagram
DFD Diagram

Are these UML be created as there is no database in my project
Any Suggestions, tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Tool probably will work with DataSet.  So you can build your own DataSet.

Comment: Who knows? You create a UML model for many purposes. Of course it's not mandatory. It just helps, when it helps. If you are not fluent in a language (and UML is one) there is not much point in using it to describe things.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the reason why you create UML diagrams. What is the goal you want to achieve with them? Have you reached that goal using the diagrams you already have? If not, what kind of additional information do you want to convey?

To answer you question directly: it doesn't matter whether an application has a database or not. You can use a class diagram to model the arrays from a user's perspective, or the C# classes from a developer's perspective. A use case diagram can be used to give an overview of the functionality. Etc.